# How to validate Freemarker template?

Tags: validation, freemarker

I am new in Freemarker and i use freemarker for email template. I have to store template in database for later use and before storing i want to validate freemarker template is valid or not. So is there any way to do that?

Comment: What are the qualities of a valid template? That it uses all of the predetermined template keys or that it doesn't attempt to use any key that isn't being passed when the template is run?

Comment: Quality Of Valid Template :- It has no syntactical errors and validate module also give message like if $ is missing. 
I want to validate template before it runs and collaborate with data.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to know that the template has no syntactical errors, you could call the `Template(String, String, Configuration)` constructor and see if it throws exception.

Comment: In my web apps that use freemarker (I have a CMS and some emailing systems) I just show a test render with placeholder values. This seems to be the easiest way for people to do a sanity check before they commit to a template.

Comment: Is there any way to do data model validation?

Comment: @JacksonKelley No, as it's generally not possible to find out what variables will be accessed by a template during parsing. Unless you heavily restrict what language features you use.

Comment: I'm not interested in doing it at parse-time, but really at any time at all.  Given a template and a data model, do all elements in the template exist in the data model?  Is this possible?  I was actually just about to write my own.

Comment: It's not possible to tell what data-model variables will be accessed, except by actually executing the template. It's just impossible to tell otherwise, except for quite simple templates.